# Combinations: How many ways can an even number of women be selected for a committee of 12 people?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A committee of 12 is to be selected from 10 men and 10 women. In how many ways can the selection be carried out if there must be an even number of women?

---

The answer is 63090, and is supposed to be written in sigma notation. The answer is written in sigma notation but I'm unsure how to format it here, so you will have to try figure out the answer for that format for this question. Anyways, my question is how do I approach this question? I know it deals with combinations because order of the selections don't matter, but I'm totally lost  from seeing answers from this question from other sites.

How to get the answer written in sigma notation? I've seen answers where 2,4,6,8 or 10 can be the number of woman in committee and corresponding to that men will be 10,8,6,4 and 2.

Sorry if what I'm asking is hard to understand I am just really confused.

### TL;DR:

### How to write the answer in sigma notation? (I am clueless)

---

NOTE --- EDIT 1: I think this is how you do the question; 2,4,6,8, 10 are the even number of possible selections of women. Along with the 2,4,6,8, 10 you will have to subtract 12 from each of those numbers every time to get the amount of men selected. From there, you do product rule of say for example, starting with (12 choose 2 women) x (12 choose 10 men) + (12 choose 4 women) x (12 choose 8 men) ........ + (12 choose 10 women) x (12  choose 2 men). This  gives the correct answer, but how to write this in sigma notation?

Answer (score 3):

We can choose $2,4,6,8$ or $10$ woman then by multiplication rule we have

$$N=\sum_{k=1}^{5} \overbrace{\binom{10}{2k}}^{\text{2k women}}\cdot\overbrace{\binom{10}{12-2k}}^{\text{12-2k men}}$$

Comment: yes that is the answer. but could you explain like the parts of how you got each individual part of the notation. like instead of 12 - 2k, what if I write 36 - 6k  or something else. you get what im trying to ask

Comment: @harold232 If we chose $2$ women, in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways, we also need to choose $12-2=10$ men  in $\binom{10}{12-2}$ ways, and so on.

Comment: although thats the correct answer, excluding the typo you made where one should be 12-2k instead of just 2k; shouldnt the top part be 12 instead of 10, since the total amount

Comment: @harold232 Yes of course! it was just a typo.

Comment: to clarify, is that 5 part on the top of the sigma notation the final number you are adding the stuff up to, and 1 at the bottom being the initial amount you plug in? Like you start with 1, then add 2,3,4 up to 5 and ending at 5? i'm new to sigma notatin

Comment: how did you figure the index and stuff? am i correct for the following assumptions? you got the 5 because 2,4,6,8,10 and 1 because you start with 2

Comment: the sigma notation is so confusing

Comment: @harold232 You only need to practice with that. Let $k$ go from $1$ to $5$ and add each term.

Comment: wait i think i understand now, the sigma thing is basically telling you what you start with(bottom) and what you add up to(top). the thing inside the sigma notation is basically product rule, with combinations of women on left side and combinations for men on right side, because to get the selections for men, you subtract the even number of women from the total of 12. am i right?

Comment: @harold232 Yes exactly! Very simple as you can see now!

Comment: Also, does the 12-2k matter? Like is it specifically only used to calculate the selections of men or can I use it for either men or women? For instance, 2k = men, 12- 2k women, for that question

Comment: @harold232 You could use $2k$ men and $12 - 2k$ women instead since the problem is symmetrical in men and women.

Comment: @harold232 Yes of course it is the same!